# How can I revert to changes made by Running Custom tools in .tt file for the .edmx?

Tags: entity-framework, metadata, edmx

I've updated my database with few new DB objects and run the solution is gives metadata error, then I run the custom tools for .tt files under .edmx folder, then it works fine.

Now, when I run the solution without DB objects created in the database then it gives the same error.

Now My question is how can revert the changes in the solution made by running the Custom Tools?
OR
Where can I view the history of changes made by running Custom tools, so that I can revert it.

Answer (score 0):

> how can revert the changes in the solution made by running the Custom Tools? OR Where can I view the history of changes made by running Custom tools

The history, and the ability to revert the change is in your source-code repository.